# "Not" Operator Inside a Handlebars Template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Take the following example which disables a button if a checkbox is not checked and enables it when checked:

Handlebars:

```
<form {{action "register" on="submit"}}>
  {{input type="checkbox" checked=isAgreed}}
  {{input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" disabled=isNotAgreed}}
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  content:{
    isAgreed:false
  },
  isNotAgreed:function(){
    return !this.get('isAgreed');
  }.property('isAgreed'),
  actions:{
    register:function(){
      alert("registered");
    }
  }
});
```

As demonstrated in this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/AhUpUNo/4/edit?html,js,output).

I am wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing this.  For example removing the `isNotAgreed` observable property and just using something in my handlebars template like `{{input type="submit" value="Register" disabled=!isAgreed}}`.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: We can't use operators inside the handlebars template as in the javascript.We can avoid observable property for these kind of requirements.Here is my soln in [jsbin.](http://jsbin.com/uBOXIVu/2/edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively you can bind a class `disabled` which will be true when `isAgreed` is `false` as follows.

```
<button type="submit" {{bind-attr class=":btn :btn-primary isAgreed::disabled"}}>Register</button>
```

Since you are using **twitter-bootstrap** also, this `disabled` class will give disabled like behaviour to the button.

Here is a simplified [bin](http://jsbin.com/utecOCu/1/edit) of your problem.

Comment: Thank you.  This one is what I was looking for. In my opinion it is the cleanest.

Answer (score 3):

In the moment doesn't exist a not operator `!`, in the binding property, of handlebar template.

You can use the computed property macro `not`, to have some syntax sugar:

So instead of:

```
isNotAgreed:function(){
  return !this.get('isAgreed');
}.property('isAgreed')
```

you can use:

```
isNotAgreed: Ember.computed.not('isAgreed')
```

You can see all the [avaliable computed macros here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_computed)

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks +1, that is a nice thing I didn't know existed in ember.  But I was really hoping to put this very simple logic into the template itself.  Is there anyway to do it even with a handlebars helper or by extending Ember.checkbox?